# Sphinx reStructured text - A reference to a section header is breaking if the reference is defined before the section header

Tags: python-sphinx

This works as expected

```
Section Header
--------------
 
  This is a section header



Refer to section above `Section Header <#section-header>`_
```

But the following does not work

```
Refer to section below  `Section Header <#section-header>`_


Section Header 
--------------

   This is a section below
```

Here is a [sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZBf-cxXqA6GXhmBIj9PcgSPOezrikBrq/view?usp=sharing) to demonstrate it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce any problem. Why not use the `:ref:` role with an explicit label ( (https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#role-ref), or with autosectionlabel (https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autosectionlabel.html)?

Comment: We are building a custom :ref: where you can refer to a anchor within the Sphinx Project or to an HTML anchor outside the project so we cannot be limited to :ref:

Comment: I still cannot reproduce any problem. Have you inspected the generated HTML? What is "a custom :ref:"? You should explain that in the question. Maybe you have written some code that messes up the cross-references.

Comment: Please try this sample here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZBf-cxXqA6GXhmBIj9PcgSPOezrikBrq/view?usp=sharing  We are building a custom role that mimics :ref: but is not limited to just anchors in the Sphinx Project

Comment: As far as I can tell, Sphinx will simply not output two sections (`div` elements in HTML) with identical `id` attributes. You have two sections named "Section Below". One of them is assigned `id="section-below"`, and the other gets `id="id1"`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem explained in a little more detail along with the solution

```
Anchor Test
===========

RST Section headers have a problem with references, refer to the `section below <#section-below>`_ that has the problem. The link does not work.

Section Below
-------------

This is a section below
```

The problem with the syntax `section below <#section-below>`_ is that the name of the section `Section Below` matches with the label in the [external link](https://sublime-and-sphinx-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/references.html#links-to-external-web-pages) syntax used `section below <#section-below>`_

I got this to work by changing the label in the external link to `my section below <#section-below>`_

```
Anchor Test
===========

RST Section headers have a problem with references, refer to the `my section below <#section-below>`_ that has the problem. The link does not work.

Section Below
-------------

This is a section below
```